# How to notify a UIView that it is about to be removed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

Is there a way to check if the view is about to be removed? I have subclassed UITableViewCell and would like to notify the cell if it is about to be thrown away by the table (my table has variable size of cells in each section, so there are times when it does throw away the cells).

Comment: Removed in what sense? `- dealloc` is called when the object is deallocated, `- willMoveToSuperview:` is called when it's removed as a subview.

Comment: Does the `willMoveToWindow:` method get called in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the following method:

```
- (void)willRemoveSubview:(UIView *)subview
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/willRemoveSubview: